# How to create class variable?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

i use different cells in my tableview, so i want to create them depends on something. But creation code is the same, only class name is different. How to make this better? Maybe create some variable 
`id classname = (indexPath.section > 3) ? FirstCell : SecondCell;`

```
if (indexPath.section >3)
{
    FirstCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:NSStringFromClass(FirstCell.class)];

    if (!cell)
        cell = [[FirstCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                reuseIdentifier:NSStringFromClass(FirstCell.class)];
    return cell;
}
else
{
    SecondCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:NSStringFromClass(SecondCell.class)];

    if (!cell)
        cell = [[SecondCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                 reuseIdentifier:NSStringFromClass(SecondCell.class)];
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a suggestion, I used a different apporach in such a situation. I moved the cell creation code to respective tableviewcell class.

```
@implementation FirstCell

+ (FirstCell *) cellForTableView:(UITableView *)aTableView
{
   FirstCell *cell = [aTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:NSStringFromClass(FirstCell.class)];
   if (!cell)
   {
      cell = [[FirstCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:NSStringFromClass(FirstCell.class)];
   }

   return cell;
}

@end
```

And the cellForIndexPath method will have a form like as follows,

```
if (indexPath.section > 3)
    return [FirstCell cellForTableView:tableView];

return [SecondCell cellForTableView:tableView];
```

Comment: Well, it a good solution, but there are still almost same code in both cell's classes.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
Class class = (indexPath.section > 3) ? FirstCell.class : SecondCell.class;
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:NSStringFromClass(class)];
if (!cell)
    cell = [[class alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                        reuseIdentifier:NSStringFromClass(class)];
return cell;
```

Comment: Maybe. Does it work for you? I tried your code, got : Use of undeclared identifier 'cell'

Comment: dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier is not a class name, but you named it in storyboard

Comment: Copy your cell classname to reuse identifier in storyboard, and u can use it.

Comment: @NiteeshGeorge if you want to let the user know that there is an error within there code please leave a comment and don't attempt to make changes to their code without there consent.

Answer (score 0):

Does this works for you?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    _tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds] style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    _tableView.delegate = self;
    _tableView.dataSource = self;
    [_tableView registerClass:[FirstCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:NSStringFromClass([FirstCell class])];
    [_tableView registerClass:[SecondCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:NSStringFromClass([SecondCell class])]; //ios 6 and above

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSString *identifier = (indexPath.section > 3) ? NSStringFromClass([FirstCell class]) : NSStringFromClass([FirstCell class]);
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
    //cell is guaranteed not to be nil if you register it before
    return cell;
}
```